# How to get the clicks coordinates python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, coordinates, game-loop

I am making a cross-zero game on python 3.5.4 with tkinter.

I have made this at the moment:

```
from sys import *
from tkinter import *
screen = Tk()
c = Canvas(width=600, height=600)
c.pack()
Line1 = c.create_line(200, 0, 200, 600)
Line2 = c.create_line(400, 0, 400, 600)
Line3 = c.create_line(0, 200, 600, 200)
Line4 = c.create_line(0, 400, 600, 400)
```

Then, I want to make to make the main loop.
And I think that it'll be better if I make it with using clicks' coordinates.

But how can I get them?
Or maybe I should make the game with using buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to access the canvas coordinates of a mouse click:

```
import tkinter as tk

def click(event):
    print(event.x, event.y)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    screen = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(width=600, height=600)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.bind('<Button-1>', click)
    screen.mainloop()
```